# How to Create a UIViewController programmatically with view from storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have a view controller designed in `Main.storyboard` named `ProfileViewController` also a corresponding class by that name. 
I can instantiate the viewController like this,

```
UIStoryboard(name: "SignUp", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ProfileViewController") as? ProfileViewController
```

However what I'd like to do is instantiate the view controller like this

```
let profileViewController = ProfileViewController(/*argument list*/)
```

Comment: is you want to show from another viewcontroller you cna use `self.present()` if not that then is not clear what do you want to achive with that code

Comment: If you want the elements you've designed in Storyboard to show up, you ***must*** instantiate it from the Storyboard. If you've designed your `ProfileViewController` purely in code, you can instantiate it with `let profileViewController = ProfileViewController(/*argument list*/)`

Answer (score 1):

Storyboard's view controllers **MUST** instantiate from `storyboard`. if you need a custom constructor function (like a initializer), you can define a simple one like this:

```
extension ProfileViewController {
    static func new(argument: any) -> ProfileViewController {
        let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "SignUp", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ProfileViewController") as! ProfileViewController
        vc.argument = argument
        return vc
    }
}
```

Note that if you want to use a real initializer, you can't use storyboard. You may use the view of the designed view controller and assign it to the view in initializer but you will loose other view controller settings.

```
extension ProfileViewController {
    convenience init(argument: Any) {
        self.init()
        self.view = UIStoryboard(name: "SignUp", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ProfileViewController").view
        self.argument = argument
    }
}
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer. I followed your instruction but I'm getting this exception "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency', reason: 'A view can only be associated with at most one view controller at a time!"  don't understand what I'm doing wrong.